# Examples from history, way forward for failed states

Tags: political-history, police

What are the historic examples of countries that were failed states and then became normal states?

To narrow it down, are there historic examples of countries that were once in a similar situation like El Salvador and Honduras (with massive gang violence, failing rule of law and a huge amount of displaced persons) but managed to become stable safe places.

Comment: Germany? As in: the *Holy Roman Empire* became *Imperial Germany* over a period a time, culminating with the unification in 1871. Italy, in a similar story.

Comment: @o.m. I find it insulting you consider pre-1871 Germany as a failed state.

Comment: Since the question was closed. I'll put a small answer here. Most states have had a period of failure, for example, when they have civil wars, when institutions are gone (no institutions and no authority means a failed state). China case: At the end of XIX century China was a failed state, they had several civil wars and external invasions, later China was being divided between powers and then it was partially occupied by Japan, after that they had a long civil war that only ended in 1949, when modern China starts. Colombia was also a failed state, but now, without guerrilla, is no longer one.

Comment: The Articles of Confederation?  Shay's rebellion.  The U S civil war?  You will probably have to define "failed state" more precisely.  Was the English Restoration an example?

Comment: @Santiago offers I think the key to the answer.  Look for any state that had a civil war or insurrection .

Comment: I dont know if this was always the case historically but during wars the faction that currently holds some territory is the de-facto state in the territory. This makes the step from rebellion to state-proper smaller. I think this part is lacking in failed states.

Comment: @Bregalad, if you look at Germany/the HRE during the 17th and 18th century, central authority clearly broke down and warlords feuded to an exceptional degree, even by the standards of the era. While the term "failed state" is mostly used to describe the present day, the HRE was more fiction than fact. Some constituent polities were better organized.

Comment: @o.m. You are confusing "a loose union of a multitude of small states" with "a failed state". Those are orthogonal. You seem to favour centralized government, but those have many issues too, look at France for example, where Paris doesn't care about the rest of the country and everything is dictated by Paris. Do you consider all federated states or loose union failed states ? The Helvetic Republic was a failed state of an attempt to centralize Switzerland. Therefore us Swiss people despise centralized states and usually leads to somewhat failed states.

Comment: @o.m. Back to Germany, the period which correspond the most of a "failed state" would be the Weimar Republic, which is exactly when they started to centralize everything in the country. After the war, the FRG, a federation of states, was successful, when the GDR, a centralized state, eventually failed.

Comment: @Bregalad, failed states are usually associated with a breakdown of (central) governments and their services, feuding clans, and general lawlessness. That matches the Thirty Years War much better than the GDR. The GDR was an utter economic failure, but the state stayed until it folded quite suddenly.